# TCP connection stalling

Tags: tcp, linux

With these two captures in mind (both illustrating the problem) we are experiencing a problem with TCP flow when we have some specific packet loss.

https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/a1a050d95269 (initial capture from linux 3.2)
https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/7e5b91e67a64 (after upgrading to linux 3.8)

Basically, the TCP connection is hanging.

In between packet 4 and 6 GH (.128) actually sent us back a reply to the SSL hello - 3 packets that didn't make it to us.
In those 3 packets they would have ACKed our initial 136 bytes and sent 3741 of their own (which can be inferred from the ACK=137 and Seq=3742 in packet 6)

Packet 6 finally makes it to us indicating they ACK 137 bytes *and* have already sent 3741 bytes to us in this stream. Which means they've sent at least 3 packets which didn't make it. **Strange to lose 3 packets in a row like that.**

My interpretation is that our reaction to packet 6 *should* be sending back an LEN=0 ACK=1 packet to .128 saying that we haven't seen any traffic from them, triggering a retransmission of their initial 3741 byte response.

That's what's causing the connection to hang, notwithstanding the initial packet loss.

I have captures taken from our end (`64.71.148.3`) while replicating the problem (hang while attempting to do a git pull from github).

The *main questions* here are:

- is my analysis of the TCP flow correct?
- Does the ultimate responsibility here lie on Linux at our end to request the retransmit?

Also:

- Is this a bug in the Linux TCP/IP stack?
- Is there something I can change to make it behave better?

[image: TCP flow graph]

#### Notes

- This is not an HTTPS-specific problem; I can replicate it by cloning over SSH
- Yes, there's packet loss, but that's what TCP is supposed to handle
- Problem initially found on with gateway at kernel 3.2. Have upgraded to 3.8.0-37-generic (ubuntu 12.04)
- Tested behind the (PAT) gateway as well as on the gateway itself
- Tested on the *other* gateway with "identical" configuration - no change
- Can reproduce quickly by running `git clone -v https://github.com/SamSaffron/pups.git; rm -rf pups` a few iterations will usually trigger it.

Comment: Is this a Github specific problem? They are currently facing a DDoS and have deployed an DDoS protection solution. These normally use heuristics to match "attack" traffic which sometimes misclassifies normal traffic and drops it. I have experienced hanging connections to github myself in the last few days.

Comment: Sebastian actually that is very good input. For the last week or so, my linux git push connections hung, I've been wondering why.

Comment: We've been working with Github to resolve, but if anyone else can demonstrate packet captures with the same problem that would be very helpful.

Comment: FWIW, I use `hg-git` with my code pushes... when I upgraded from `hg-git==0.5.0` to `hg-git==0.7.0`, my tcp sessions quit hanging when I run `hg push git+ssh://git@github.com:mpenning/ciscoconfparse.git`

Answer (score 3):

This smells like an MTU issue - a symptom of MTU problems is packets with payload being consistently dropped while the rest pass through unmolested.

Try manually setting the MTU of the appropriate interface at your end to something lower than the default.  If this makes the problem go away, then you have a path MTU discovery issue.  This is usually caused by a firewall along the path unwisely dropping the ICMP packets that facilitate path MTU discovery.

Comment: Normally I'd agree but I would expect more than 3741 to be missing.